# confusion on full process of setting up heroku postgresdb for python app

Tags: python, heroku, heroku-postgres

so I have followed this guide https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-heroku-postgres#connecting-in-python and provisioned a database for my heroku app. In my server code, I added the database url and ssl require. However, how does my server actually get permission to write to the database?
Locally, with psycopg2 you would have :
conn = psycopg2.connect(database="dbName", user = "postgres", password = "password", host = "127.0.0.1", port = "5432"), and thats how your server authenticates itself and has permission to write onto the postgres db. With heroku however, none of that extra information is provided except for the db url link. What is the remaining process that I must to do to allow my server deployed on heroku to have permission to write to its associated provisioned database?

Comment: All of that information (hostname, username, password, etc) is typically encoded in the `DATABASE_URL` value. Have you looked it?

Comment: It looks like heroku provides you with [actual example code](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-heroku-postgres#connecting-in-python) showing how to use it in Python.

Comment: so there is no further authentication needed beyond that point?

Comment: I'm really not sure how to answer that question: the database url includes the username and password you need to access the database. What additional authentication are you expecting?

Comment: now that I read what you wrote I realize I had completely lost my marbles. But it was this https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quick-start-heroku-connect-cli#optional-step-9-verify-setup link that made me think I had additional authentication to do